# html table elements not aligning with the row above

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm having trouble with styling a table.

http://jsfiddle.net/Gs7Vx/5/

```
<tr>
    <td class="label">HRS</td>
    <td class="label">INSP</td>
</tr>
```

I want the "HRS" and "INSP" fields in this row to line up with the input fields above them.  I've tried a lot of things, none of them have worked.  I'm sure there's a simple solution and I'm just missing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the inputs to line up with the labels, you need to

A) add a blank `<td></td>` to the second row (because the row above it has 3 cells and it only has 2), and

B) remove `float:right;` from the `.label` class.

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/VmcGm/) as the example.  I only added the `<td></td>` to the row on the first out of your four sections, but they are all identical, so you get the point.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to setup your table like this:

```
            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <tr>
                <td>HRS</td>
                <td>
                  <input type="text" class="smallinput">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>INSP</td>
                <td>
                  <input type="text" class="smallinput">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                  <textarea name="textarea" rows="12" class="txt"></textarea>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
```

Next time format your code before posting. You did not make your intent clear. SO we have multiple people giving you different answers because we are formatting your code and trying to figure out what you really want to do. Make sure you have the same number of `<td>`s in each row as well or use colspan to make up for the missing ones.

Comment: You should, give the people who helped you out with your question some feedback to let them know if they are helping or not. Also check which answer helped you to figure out your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gs7Vx/10/)**.

the row above that row containing only two `<td>`s with content **'hrs'** and **'insp'**, contains 3 `<td>`s. Hence you need to put a blank td in that row(i.e. with **'hrs'** and **'insp'**) too.

Besides you need to remove the style `float:right` and add the style `position:relative` in the style definition of the `.smallinput`-class.

- **O/P**

[image]

### This solves your problem..

Answer (score 0):

I took it out of these `<td class="label"></td>` and put it right in front and it worked fine.

```
INSP<input type="text" class="smallinput"></td><td width="40px" style="font-size:12px">HRS<input type="text" class="smallinput">
```

(using chrome.)

Answer (score 0):

your code is all wrong. First of all, you have unclosed elements, all input elements should end with />

Then, to have everything in a line, do it like this:

```
<tr>
<td>label</td>
<td>input</td>
<td>label</td>
<td>input</td>
</tr>
```

an then style as needed

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
<tr>
    <td class="fieldtitle"><i style="color:#fff;" class="icon"></i>
    </td>
    <td width="40px" style="font-size:12px">
        <input type="text" class="smallinput"><span style="font-size:10px">HRS</span>
    </td>
    <td width="40px" style="font-size:12px">
        <input type="text" class="smallinput"><span style="font-size:10px">INSP</span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```